# If $K(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ and linear in $y$, is $\|K(x,\cdot)\|$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, equicontinuity

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space with norm $\|\cdot\|_H$, and $K : \mathbb R^n \times H \to \mathbb R$ is a function such that $K(x,y)$ is continuous in $x$ and a bounded linear operator in $y$. Need $f(x) = \|K(x,\cdot)\|$ be a continuous function, where
$$\|K(x,\cdot)\| = \sup_{\|y\|_H = 1}|K(x,y)|?$$
If the family of functions $\mathcal F := \{K(\cdot,y) : y\in H\}$ is equicontinuous, then the answer is affirmative, since
$$|f(b) - f(a)| \leq \|K(b,\cdot)-K(a,\cdot)\| \leq \varepsilon$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$, as soon as $a$ is in a neighborhood of $b$ small enough that $|K(b,y) - K(a,y)| < \varepsilon$ for all $y\in H$. When $H = \mathbb R^m$ equipped with the Euclidean norm, then this assertion should be true as well. In this case, there exists a matrix-valued function $A : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^{1\times m}$ such that $K(x,y) = A(x)y$ for every $(x,y)\in \mathbb R^{n+m}$. If we write $A(x) = \left[\alpha_1(x),  \cdots, \alpha_m(x)\right]$ then we see $f(x) = \|A(x)\| = \sqrt{\alpha_1(x)^2 + \cdots + \alpha_m(x)^2}$, and since each $\alpha_i(x) := K(x,e_i)$ (where $e_i$ is a basis element of $\mathbb R^m$) is continuous, we see $f$ is continuous.

However, I have novice experience with Hilbert spaces, and I have some doubt that the assertion holds in a completely general context. Therefore **I was hoping someone could point me in the correct direction of a proof, or help furnish a counter example.**

Comment: For reference, this was just a question I came up with while I was thinking about operator norms and Hilbert spaces.

Comment: I'll just note that if continuity wrt $x$ for each fixed $y$ is replaced by Lipschitz or even just Holder continuity then $x \mapsto K(x,\cdot)$ will be Lipschitz or Hölder by using Banach-Steinhaus on the family $\left(\frac{K(x, \cdot) - K(x', \cdot)}{\|x - x'\|}\right)$ indexed by $(x,x')$, $x \neq x'$, thus in particular by continuity of the norm your result will be valid. This is a generalisation or alternative of your equicontinuity case because I don't assume known the fact that the Hölder constants are bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no unfortunately. It is easier to work with sequences in this context hence we will need this lemma to built a counterexample,

**Lemma :** If $(u_n)_{n \geqslant 1}$ is a sequence of elements of $H^*$ that weakly converges toward $0$, there exists a continuous $K : \mathbb{R} \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is linear in the second variable such that for all $n \geqslant 1$, $K\!\left(\frac{1}{n},\cdot\right) = u_n$ and $K(0,\cdot) = 0$.

Indeed, let us define for all $x \geqslant 1$, $K(x,y) = u_1(y)$, for all $x \leqslant 0$, $K(x,y) = 0$ and for all $0 < x \leqslant 1$, let $n = \left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor$ is the only integer that verifies $\frac{1}{n + 1} < x  \leqslant \frac{1}{n}$ and,
$$
K(x,y) = \frac{x - (n + 1)^{-1}}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}u_n(y) + \frac{n^{-1} - x}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}u_{n + 1}(y).
$$
$K$ is clearly linear in the second variable and each $K(x,\cdot)$ is continuous. Moreover, $K(\cdot,y)$ is continuous for each fixed $y$ because it is affine by part (the continuity at $x = 0$ is ensured by the weak convergence of $u_n$ toward $0$). The sequence $(u_n)$ is uniformly bounded by the uniform boundedness principle hence for all $0 < x \leqslant 1$,
\begin{align*}
\|K(x,\cdot)\| & = \left\|\frac{x - (n + 1)^{-1}}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}u_n + \frac{n^{-1} - x}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}u_{n + 1}\right\|\\
& \leqslant \left|\frac{x - (n + 1)^{-1}}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}\right|\|u_n\| + \left|\frac{n^{-1} - x}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}\right|\|u_{n + 1}\|\\
& \leqslant \frac{x - (n + 1)^{-1}}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}\sup_{n}\|u_n\| + \frac{n^{-1} - x}{n^{-1} - (n + 1)^{-1}}\sup_n\|u_n\|\\
& = \sup_n\|u_n\|,
\end{align*}
and the same equality trivially holds for $x \leqslant 0$ and $x \geqslant 1$. It implies the total continuity of $K$ because for all $x,x',y,y'$,
\begin{align*}
|K(x',y') - K(x,y)| & \leqslant |K(x',y') - K(x',y)| + |K(x',y) - K(x,y)|\\
& \leqslant \sup_n\|u_n\|\|y' - y\| + |K(x',y) - K(x,y)|\\
& \rightarrow 0,
\end{align*}
when $(x',y') \rightarrow (x,y)$ by continuity of $K$ with respect to $x$ when $y$ is fixed. It proves the lemma.

Now, to build the counterexample, consider for example $H = \mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{N})$ and for all $n$, $u_n(y) = y_n$, which weakly converges toward $0$ but it doesn't converge strongly because for all $n$, $\|u_n\| = 1$. Let $K$ be given by the lemma. We have for all $n \geqslant 1$, $\left\|K\!\left(\frac{1}{n},\cdot\right)\right\| = \|u_n\| = 1$ but $\|K(0,\cdot)\| = 0$.

Notice however that such a $K : \mathbb{R}^n \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is always lower semi-continuous. Indeed, if $x_m \rightarrow x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then for all $y$, $K(x_m,y) \rightarrow K(x,y)$ hence $K(x_m,\cdot) \rightarrow K(x,\cdot)$ weakly so $\|K(x,\cdot)\| \leqslant \liminf_m\|K(x_m,\cdot)\|$ by weak convergence.